# First submit through update action is dirty even though none of the attributes have changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

**Update**

I had to change the piece of the code below to this for it to work properly:

```
attrs_to_check.each do |attr|      
    if self.send("#{attr}_changed?") && ( !self.send("#{attr}_was").nil? && !self.send(attr).nil? )
        self.last_updated_hash[attr] = DateTime.now
    end    
end
```

But I'd still like to understand why I need to add the extra if statement logic.  It seems like it should be unnecessary.

**Original**

I am adding a serialized hash to my model to record the datetime that certain fields in the model were last updated.  The strange thing is that this works fine except for on the first update action, where it seems to treat everything as dirty regardless if changes were made to those particular attributes.  And what seems even more strange, it treats it as dirty even if there weren't any changes made to any of the attributes (just click the submit button on the edit form without making a change).  Why might that be?

Here's the code for the model:

```
class ResearchCompany < ActiveRecord::Base  
    attr_accessible :name, :revenue_stats, :customer_qty_stats, :last_updated_hash       

    serialize :last_updated_hash, Hash

    before_save :set_last_updated_hash

    def set_last_updated_hash
        attrs_to_check = ['revenue_stats', 'customer_qty_stats']

        attrs_to_check.each do |attr|      
            if self.send("#{attr}_changed?")
                self.last_updated_hash[attr] = DateTime.now
            end    
        end      
    end
end
```

And the relevant parts of the controller:

```
class Admin::ResearchCompaniesController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @company = ResearchCompany.new(params[:research_company])
        if @company.save
            redirect_to admin_research_companies_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
     end

    def update
        @company = ResearchCompany.find(params[:id])
        if @company.update_attributes(params[:research_company])
            redirect_to admin_research_companies_path
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end
end
```

When the record is first created:

```
self.last_updated_hash = {}
```

But when the record is first updated, even if the revenue_stats or customer_qty_stats attributes were not changed:

```
self.last_updated_hash = { "revenue_stats"=>Sat, 19 Oct 2013 11:29:48 -0400, "customer_qty_stats"=>Sat, 19 Oct 2013 11:29:48 -0400 }
```

But from that point forward, the datetime stored in the hash is only updated when one of those individual attributes changes.  That is the proper behavior.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: What is `attrs_to_check`?  Edit: found it, sorry.

Comment: This is only a hunch since I can't see your views, but what might be happening is that on first update, the attributes are in fact changing from `nil` to `''` (the empty string). This could be the case if your create form doesn't include these fields, but the update form does. If you don't want to treat blank values as distinct from nil values, there is a useful gem called [nilify_blanks](https://github.com/rubiety/nilify_blanks).